# liferay approved content missing on restart of the server

Tags: liferay

When the content is modified in the Portal , a new version is created and Published and this becomes approved Version . Yet when we restart the liferay server ,all modifications are lost in the new version. Please help me out to get this sorted.

This issue seems not solved yet after doing the below change too.
Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ressource importer, you must disable developer mode in resource importer configurations.
Go to :

```
src/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties
```

and then update the property.

```
resources-importer-developer-mode-enabled=false
```

Comment: is this activated by default ?

Comment: Yes it is activated by default